# What do move and key comparison mean in c++?

Tags: c++, time, complexity-theory

Followings are written in a ppt about Insertion Sort in my class:

```
void insertionSort(DataType theArray[], int n) {
  for (int unsorted = 1; unsorted < n; ++unsorted) {

    DataType nextItem = theArray[unsorted];
    int loc = unsorted;

    for (;(loc > 0) && (theArray[loc-1] > nextItem); --loc)
       theArray[loc] = theArray[loc-1];

    theArray[loc] = nextItem;
  }
}
```

-

```
Running time depends on not only the size of the array but also the contents of the array.
Best-case:       O(n)
Array is already sorted in ascending order.
Inner loop will not be executed.
>>>> The number of moves: 2*(n-1)        O(n)
>>>> The number of key comparisons: (n-1)    O(n)
Worst-case:      O(n2)
Array is in reverse order:
Inner loop is executed p-1 times, for p = 2,3, …, n
The number of moves: 2*(n-1)+(1+2+...+n-1)= 2*(n-1)+ n*(n-1)/2   O(n2)
The number of key comparisons: (1+2+...+n-1)= n*(n-1)/2          O(n2)
Average-case:    O(n2)
We have to look at all possible initial data organizations.
So, Insertion Sort is O(n2)
```

What exacly are move and key comparison?? I couldn't find an explanaiton on Google.

Comment: When you sort something, you will have to move things around, right? The "key" is the part of the object that determines how it should be sorted. Doesn't have to be all of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me word the algorithm first.

- Assume at a given time there are two part of array. index `0` to index `loc - 1` is sorted in ascending order and index `loc` to `n - 1` is unsorted.
- Start with element at `loc`, find its correct place in sorted part of the array and insert it there.

So now there are two loops:

1. First outer loop, starts with `loc = 1` to `loc = n`, basically partitions the array in sorted and unsorted part.
2. Second inner loop finds position of element at `loc` in the sorted part of array ( `0` to `loc - 1`).

For the inner loop, to find correct location, you have to compare element at `loc` with, in worst case, all the elements in sorted part of array. This is key comparison.

To insert, you have to create a void in sorted part of the array for element at `loc`. This is done by swapping each element in sorted part to the next element. This is move.

Answer (score 0):

Move is the number of swaps it has to perform in order to sort the data and the keys are the data that is compered.